# Blender seems to break when I unfocus from it

Tags: error

Recently I've been getting weird visual glitches affecting viewport, properties, and outliner.
I tried searching for a answer but seem to got none on google. Someone told me it was likely a driver issue with my computer though nothing other than blender is affected. Also I can reproduce it if I leave it alone for a little bit...
[image]

Comment: 1. Reinstall Blender using a .zip 
2. Try checking your drivers

Comment: it was a driver issue and I had to update